# Java reading a CSV file's line and storing it into a List of Lists

Tags: java, arrays, list, csv, split

I have a CSV file, looking like this:

```
First, Surname, Age    
Jim, Halpert, 35
Dwight, Schrute, 38
```

And I need to store it by Column (List of First names, list of surnames, list of ages). And I created a list of lists that would store this representation.

```
List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] myRow = row.split(",");
            for (int j=0; j<COLUMN_COUNT; j++)
            {
                myList.get(j).add(i,myRow[j]);
                System.out.println(data.get(j).get(i));

            }
            i++;
        }
```

My question is since I know what COLUMN_COUNT is, why doesn't this work? I am just trying to go through every line, and in every line, I separate the CSV to an array and then want to store this in a column-based list of lists.

The actual error I am getting is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

and the error happens on the line `myList.get(j)...`

Thanks

***Edit***

Some of you suggested working examples, which now I am using, so thank you very much for that! Now, I am thinking that I might use Java Streams, so it would take less code and be more optimized. However when I do:

```
List<List<String>> myList = Files.lines(Path.of(csvPath)) // Stream<String>
                    //  .skip(1) // (optional) skip a header line
                    .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s*,\\s*")) // split by comma and trim whitespaces
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()) // get list of columns
                    ) // Stream<List<String>>
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I only get something like this as a result:

```
[Jim, Halpert, 35]
[Dwigth, Schrute, 38]
```

But I actually need

```
[Jim, Dwight]
[Helpert, Schrute]
[35,38]
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you detail "it doesn't work", can you be more specific ?

Comment: @azro my bad, added the error that I am getting

Comment: @Sorin `myList` is declared and initialized, do I need to do something else? I looked at what you sent me and I am not sure how it applies to my case

Comment: If you plan on using those List of Lists anywhere, then you're better off building a Class suited for the task.

Comment: You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created `myList` but it is empty, it doesn't contains lists to handle values of each columns, you need to pre-fill it

```
// Add a list for each column
for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN_COUNT; j++) {
    myList.add(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Then you may add the date, and you don't need an `i` to set the value in the sublist, just append it after the other values

```
while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] myRow = row.split(",");
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN_COUNT; j++) {
        myList.get(j).add(myRow[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you will ned something like this

```
    int column_count = 3;
    List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < column_count; i++) {
        myList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null){
        String[] split = row.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            myList.get(i).add(split[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much! Exactly what I have been looking for

Comment: @SamuelV. wuld be great if you can flag the answer as solution ;)

Comment: Will do! You were one of the first to answer and really helpful, I just need to sort this Java streams stuff (see the edit), and then I will flag your answer as a solution and close this topic, dw, I am keeping it in my mind :))

Answer (score 1):

If the format of CSV file is simple (without double quoted strings, escaped commas, etc.), such file could be read in a simpler way using Stream API with new `Files::lines` method providing a stream of Strings:

```java
List<List<String>> data = Files.lines(Path.of(csvFileName)) // Stream<String>
    //  .skip(1) // (optional) skip a header line
        .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s*,\\s*")) // split by comma and trim whitespaces
            .collect(Collectors.toList()) // get list of columns
        ) // Stream<List<String>>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Otherwise, appropriate library should be used to read CSV data like [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

---

**Update**
In order to convert a stream of string lines/rows into columnar view `List<List<String>>`, the algorithm is as follows:

1. Split each line by the delimiter into string array
2. Convert each array into stream of map entries where key is a column index (use `flatMap`)
3. Use `collectingAndThen` to collect incoming map entries into a map, and convert the latter into `List<List<String>>`:

```java
static List<List<String>> toColumnList(Stream<String> lines) {
    return lines
        .map(line -> line.split("\\s*,\\s*")) // Stream<String[]>
        .flatMap(arr -> IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(i, arr[i])) // Stream<Integer, String>, i - column index
        )
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getKey, // group by column indexes
                Collectors.mapping(
                    Map.Entry::getValue, 
                    Collectors.toList()
            )), // Map<Integer, List<String>>
            map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values()) // convert map values to List<List<String>>
        ));
}
```

Test

```java
System.out.println(toColumnList(
    Stream.of("John, Doe, 38", "Dwight, Wright, 45", "Jim, Beam, 40")
));
```

Output

```
[[John, Dwight, Jim], [Doe, Wright, Beam], [38, 45, 40]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will go with this solution, can I just ask, if I will use skip(1), but I want the first line (i.e. First, Surname, Age ) to be stored in a simple array of string which would look like [First,Surname,Age] How can I achieve this with Java streams? Thanks!

Comment: Then you don't need to use `skip(1)` and the first element `data.get(0)` will contain the column headers

Comment: I see, and is there something like `break` with streams, such that I can say, read only these first **n** lines?

Comment: There's `Stream::limit(int n)` method for this purpose, which stops the stream as soon as `n` elements are processed (or stream is finished whichever occurs first)

Comment: Hi @Alex Rudenko , sorry to ask you again, but I think your code is doing something else than what I meant in my question, it is reading by rows, but I actually want to store it by column, please see the edit to see what is the issue, thanks!

Comment: @SamuelV. please check the updated solution to get list of columns using Stream API